# Ionic cordova-plugin-facebook4 Crash on app startup

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, facebook-login

after installing the cordova plugin facebook using the commands:

> sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="xxx" --variable APP_NAME="xxx"
>   and the
>
> sudo npm install @ionic-native/facebook

and after adding the Android platform 7.1.1 when I run the app crashes immediately after the splash screen with no logs.

If I open Android Studio from the errors log I can read the following error:

> Caused by: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.

I attached the ionic info:

> ```
> Ionic:
> ```
>
> ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
>   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
>
> Cordova:
>
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)    Cordova
>   Platforms     : android 7.1.4    Cordova Plugins       : no
>   whitelisted plugins (25 plugins total)
>
> System:
>
> ios-deploy : 1.9.4    NodeJS     : v8.11.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
>   npm        : 6.4.1    OS         : macOS    Xcode      : Xcode 10.2
>   Build version 10E125

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself.

I modify the AndroidManifest insert this 3 lines of code

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName" android:value="@string/fb_app_name" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/fb_app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" />
```

I don't know why the lines are not added automatically.